# After editing CSS with SASS my burger button stopped working

Tags: javascript, css, sass

So I have edited my code adding SASS compiler and I have found that my burger button and nav menu stopped working, even though all the classes are added after I inspect the page. Console is not bringing any errors and I really don't know what is causing the problem

That's the scss code with automation:

```
nav {
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $primDark;

    .nav-logo {
        margin-left: auto;
        color: $primLight;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 50%;
        margin-right: auto;

        li {
            filter: brightness(0.9);
            list-style-type: none;
            transition: 0.2s ease; 

            &:hover {
                filter: brightness(1);
                transform: scale(1.05);
                color: $primLight;
            }

            a {
                color: $primLight;
                text-decoration: none;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
    }

    .burger {
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;

        div {
            width: 30px;
            height: 3px;
            background-color: $primLight;
            margin: 5px;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .toggle {
            .line1 {
                transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
            }
            .line2 {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .line3 {
                transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
            }
        }
    }

    .nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}`

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    nav {
        justify-content: space-around;

        .nav-logo {
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .nav-links {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            right: 0px;
            height: 90vh;
            top: 10vh;
            background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.945);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;

            li {
                opacity: 0;
                a {
                    font-size: 30px;
                }
            }
        }

        .burger {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}


@keyframes navLinksFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

And that's the js function:

```
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {

        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {

            if(link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = 'navLinksFade 0.5s ease forwards ' + index/(7+0.9) + 's';
            }

        });
        // X
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance for every help!

Comment: You can check the output CSS after SASS compilation with your old CSS and try to see what is missing/changed

Comment: Theres a " ` " just before your media query?

Comment: @NowresRafed I actually tried doing it this way, but everything seems pretty much the same. I do wonder how the navLinksFade is complied through sass and I'm not sure if that should be outside of nav or inside. Anyway, it seems like the correct classes are added so I really cannot find the problem